# Can IEquatable compare custom objects having a list property of other custom objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to compare two custom class objects of the same type. The custom class being compared has a List property which is filled with items of another custom type. Is this possible by inheriting IEquatable?

I couldn't figure out how to make this work by modifying [MSDN's code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compare class objects containing List properties of a custom type.

I did successfully derive from the [EqualityComparer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make a separate comparison class (code below), but I'd like to implement the comparison ability in the actual classes being compared. Here's what I have so far:

**EDIT: This doesn't work after all. My apologies - I've been working on this awhile and I may have pasted incorrect example code. I'm working on trying to find my working solution...**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     // Test the ContractComparer.

        Contract a = new Contract("Contract X", new List<Commission>() { new Commission(1), new Commission(2), new Commission(3) });
        Contract b = new Contract("Contract X", new List<Commission>() { new Commission(1), new Commission(2), new Commission(3) });

        ContractComparer comparer = new ContractComparer();

        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(a, b));
    // Output returns True. I can't get this to return
        // True when I inherit IEquatable in my custom classes
        // if I include the list property ("Commissions") in my
        // comparison.

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Contract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Commission> Commissions { get; set; }
    public Contract(string name, List<Commission> commissions)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Commissions = commissions;
    }
}

public class Commission
{
    public int ID;
    public Commission(int id)
    {
        this.ID = id;
    }
}

public class ContractComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contract>
{

    public bool Equals(Contract a, Contract b)
    {
        //Check whether the objects are the same object.  
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)) return true;

        //Check whether the contracts' properties are equal.  
        return a != null && b != null && a.Name.Equals(b.Name) && a.Commissions.Equals(b.Commissions);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Contract obj)
    {
        int hashName = obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        int hashCommissions = obj.Commissions.GetHashCode();

        return hashName ^ hashCommissions;
    }
}
```

Comment: `a.Commissions.Equals(b.Commissions)` won't cut it because it will only detect the same list, not two separate lists (even if their contents are identical).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement some kind of comparer for `Commission`, e.g. by implementing `Commission : IEquatable<Commission>`, then use it:

```
... && a.Commissions.SequenceEqual(b.Commissions)
```

Comment: Correct! Thank you. I didn't know there was a separate method for comparing a sequence of objects.

Comment: Just a note, this will throw an exception if a.Commissions is null